# Tailwindcss & AlpineJs Transition Issue

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am trying to learn Tailwind CSS & AlpineJs, and I am testing the element transition animation, targeting the height of the element. However there are two problems.

1. I don't see the transition animation
2. When the element show/hide the page scrolls up.

Can anyone help me understand or fix this? Here is the code:

```html
<div x-data="{ openForm: false }">
   <div id="form-container" x-show="openForm" class="transition-all" x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="h-0" x-transition:enter-end="h-full" x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200" x-transition:leave-start="h-full" x-transition:leave-end="h-0">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ipsum suscipit, facere commodi sit nam laboriosam iure natus quae nesciunt provident fugiat enim quo. Molestias, ad sit. Unde, laudantium quas!
      This is to add the item.
      <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150" @click="openForm = false">
      Cancel
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="mt-5">
      <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150" @click="openForm = true" x-show="!openForm" style="display: none;">
      Add New
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so...

1. instead of `x-show` I used `x-show.transition`
2. Position the button before the element.